# azure function executions does not appear under monitor tab

Tags: azure-functions

I have below queue trigger azure function. it runs successfully when there are queue messages.
but azure portal monitor does NOT capture successful runs. Success count is always zero.

```
        public class SendTestAlertFn
        {
        private readonly ILogger<SendTestAlert> log;
        private readonly AppSettings appSettings;
        private readonly ISendAlertService sendAlertService;
      

        public SendTestAlertFn(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings, ILogger<SendTestAlert> log, ISendAlertService sendAlertService)
        {
            this.appSettings = appSettings.Value;
            this.log = log;
            this.sendAlertService = sendAlertService;
        }
        
        [FunctionName("TestFn")]
        public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("testqueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] string msgIn)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"started");

            await sendAlertService.SendTestAlertAsync();
        }
```

Monitor tab is always like this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The azure monitor tab reflects count based on the logs. When I change my host.json log level from warning to information it started to capture.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "batchSize": 1
    }
  }
}
```